# AngularJS form: formName.$valid is always been true

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, ng-messages

I have a form in my angular application and the html code is as below, but formName.$valid is always true even though the input fields are blank.

```
<form name="contactForm" novalidate ng-submit="processForm(formData)" autocomplete="off">
            <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="contactName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name*" ng-model="formData.contactName">
                <!--<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorName"></span>-->
            </div>
            <div id="email-group" class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="contactEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email*" ng-model="formData.contactEmail">
                <!--<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorSuperhero"></span>-->
            </div>
            <div id="phone-group" class="form-group">
                <input type="tel" name="contactPhone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone*" ng-model="formData.contactPhone">
                <!--<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorPhone"></span>-->
            </div>
            <div id="content-group" class="form-group">
                <textarea  rows="5" cols="50" name="contactMessage" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" ng-model="formData.contactMessage"></textarea>
                <!--<span class="help-block" ng-show="errorContent"></span>-->
            </div>
            <div class="btn-block">
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="contactForm.formData.$invalid" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt"></span> Submit!
                </button>
                <button ng-disabled="contactForm.formData.$dirty" type="reset" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Reset!
                </button>
            </div>
</form>
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have validation set on any of the elements, so the form is always valid. If you want a field to be non-empty you can make so by writing:

```
<input type="text" name="contactName" class="form-control" placeholder="Name*" ng-model="formData.contactName" required>
```